# Interactions between pointers and classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, c++11

I've recently been working to learn c++ coming from a background in java and other high level languages. I've been having some issues with pointers and objects and I have yet to find a good resource that explains exactly how to manipulate objects created with custom classes using pointers.

I've written a simple program to attempt to narrow down where my problem is.

The last two blocks of code at the bottom on this class are wrong and I'd bet that I've also done some stuff wrong in the other parts. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Point {
public: 
    float x;
    float y;    
public: 
    Point(float x, float y) {
        this->x=x;
        this->y=y;
    }
    Point() {
        x=0.0f;
        y=0.0f;
    }
    ~Point() {
        x=0.0f;
        y=0.0f;
    }
};

class Place {
public: 
    string name;
    Point location;
public: 
    //Constructor with arguements.
    Place(string nam, Point loc) {
        name = nam;
        location = loc;
    }
    //Default constructor.
    Place() {
        name = "Default";
        location = {0.0f,0.0f};
    }
    //Destructor. This object contains no pointers so nothing to delete.
    ~Place() {

    }
public: 
    void setName(string nam) {
        name = nam;
    }
    void setLocation(Point loc) {
        location = loc;
    }
};

class PointerToAPlace {
public: 
    Place *place;
public:
    PointerToAPlace(Place *pl) {
        *place = *pl;
    }
    ~PointerToAPlace() {
        delete place;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Make some places and hope they don't segfault.\n";


    /*Object created with default constructor. Will be automatically deleted at the end of this scope.*/
    Place placeA;
    std::cout << "Place named " << placeA.name.c_str() << " is at " << placeA.location.x << "," << placeA.location.y << " and is lovely.\n";
    //Output: Place named Default is at 0,0 and is lovely.


    /*Object created with bracket constructor. Will be automatically deleted at the end of this scope.*/
    Place placeB = {"Lordran", Point{12.2f,99.3f}};
    std::cout << "Place named " << placeB.name.c_str() << " is at " << placeB.location.x << "," << placeB.location.y << " and is lovely.\n";
    //Output: Place named Lordran is at 12.2,99.3 and is lovely.


    /*Object created with new keyword. This is a pointer and must be explicitly deleted.*/
    Place *placeC = new Place("Drangleic", Point{-123.34f,69.69f});
    std::cout << "Place named " << placeC->name.c_str() << " is at " << placeC->location.x << "," << placeC->location.y << " and is lovely.\n";
    delete placeC;
    //Output: Place named Drangleic is at -123.34,69.69 and is lovely.


    /*Array of objects, created with default constructor and not assigned any values. Will be automatically deleted at the end of this scope.*/
    Place placeD[3];
    std::cout << "Here are some places named: ";
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        std::cout << placeD[i].name.c_str();
        std::cout << (i<2 ? ", " : ". ");
    }
    std::cout << "They are quite the places!\n";
    //Output: Here are some places named: Default, Default, Default. They are quite the places!    


    /*Array of objects, created with default constructor and then assigned values. Will be automatically deleted at the end of this scope.*/
    Place placeE[5];
    string namesA[5] = {"Boletaria", "Stonefang", "Latria", "Shrine of Storms", "Valley of Defilement"};
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        placeE[i].setName(namesA[i]);
        placeE[i].setLocation(Point{1.23f, 3.21f});
    }
    std::cout << "Here are some places named: ";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        std::cout << placeE[i].name.c_str();
        std::cout << (i<4 ? ", " : ". ");
    }
    std::cout << "They are quite the places!\n";
    //Output: Here are some places named: Boletaria, Stonefang, Latria, Shrine of Storms, Valley of Defilement. They are quite the places!


    /*Trying to do a pointer to an array of objects.*/
    Place *placeF[7];
    string namesB[7] = {"Astora", "Carim", "Thoroughland", "Catarina", "Baulder", "Vinheim", "Zena"};
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        placeF[i]->setName(namesB[i]);
        placeF[i]->setLocation(Point{2.23f, 6.21f});
    }
    std::cout << "Here are some places named: ";
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        std::cout << placeF[i]->name.c_str();
        std::cout << (i<6 ? ", " : ". ");
    }
    std::cout << "They are quite the places!\n";
    //Output: SEGFAULT D:

    /*Trying to put a pointer to a place into an object, then delete it.*/
    Place *placeG = new Place("Anor Londo", Point{-12312.34f,33.69f});
    PointerToAPlace pnt = {placeG};
    std::cout << "Place named " << pnt.place->name.c_str() << " is at " << pnt.place->location.x << "," << pnt.place->location.y << " and is lovely.\n";
    //Output: SEGFAULT :(

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: First of all, this shouldn't even compile. `namesB` has too many strings in the initializer. Anyway, you're using uninitialized pointers as if they pointed to a valid object. I would also consider posting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com for tips on how to use the language better (e.g., the useless destructor you have for `Point`).

Comment: Kudos for learning about all the ways to create objects in C++ and how they are managed instead of just using `new` everywhere, like we often see with beginners from Java.

Comment: Suggest http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PointerToAPlace(Place *pl) {
    *place = *pl;
}
```

This is wrong, if what you're trying to do is store the pointer then do that:

```
PointerToAPlace(Place* pl) {
    place = pl;
}
```

Or better yet, use the constructor initializer list:

```
PointerToAPlace(Place* pl) : place(p1) {
}
```

Your current code doesn't set `place` so it contains a junk value pointing to who knows where, then dereferences it (which is undefined behaviour).

You also need to be careful about copying a `PointerToAPlace`, currently if you copy it you get two objects both holding the same pointer, and both will try to delete it.

IMHO once you've learnt how the syntax works and how to use `new` / `delete` you should stop using them and use smart pointers instead.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot more sense and everything is compiling/running now. I'll also look into how copying works in c++ in regards to pointers. In other languages I always define a specific copy() method for classes that makes sure not to share any pointers with the original. I assume I should do the same in c++.

Comment: That's what a copy constructor is for.

Answer (score 3):

```
class PointerToAPlace {
public: 
    Place *place;
public:
    PointerToAPlace(Place *pl) {
        *place = *pl;
    }
    ~PointerToAPlace() {
        delete place;
    }
};
```

This is wrong for a start. You're deferencing `place` before making it point anywhere.

Presumably you meant `place = pl`; the `*` is part of the type, not the name.

This will be clearer to you if you write your pointer declarations as `Place* pl`, not `Place *pl`; don't listen to the naysayers from the 1970s who obsess over the edge-case of multi-variable declarations, as those are the *only* downside of this notation.

Comment: Multi-variable declarations is like: int i, j, k; or int i=0, j=0, k=0; right?

Answer (score 2):

```
/*Trying to do a pointer to an array of objects.*/
Place *placeF[7];
```

No, this is an array of seven (uninitialized) pointers to `Place`. So when you dereference them you get segfault.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a copy constructor to your classes.
If there is none you will get into trouble when a class instance is pushed on the stack.
A copy constructor is a constructor that take the same class instance as parameter:

```
Point(Point & original)
{
  // initialize this with original
}
```

EDIT: Add missing '&' in code snippet.

Comment: Good point in general, but that's not a valid copy constructor, it needs to take its parameter by reference. Otherwise calling it will try to copy the object to initialize the argument, which calls the copy constructor, which tries to copy the argument, which calls the copy constructor, which ...

Comment: Point does not require a copy constructor.